# Converting a table of repeating 3 colums for 31 occurrences

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a Excel spreadsheet of 31 occurrences of repeating 3 columns (1: Question; 2: Answer; 3: Answer Category). Not that this matters all that much, but there are 43 rows, including both values and spaces (nulls).
I need to create a table of 3 columns only (Question, Answer, Category), and included every 3rd column of the original table in each, starting with Col 1 (Question), Col 2 (Answer), & Col 3 (Category).
I'm trying to use the `List.Alternate` function, but I can't seem get all three columns correct.

Any thoughts?

I tried various formats of the `List.Alternate` (and researched other List and table functions that did not seem to do what I needed).

Comment: Please post sample input and desired output.  Its hard to imagine what your data looks like based on text description

Answer (score 0):

I can't picture what your data looks like, since you didn't provide a sample, but on the off chance this helps, this stacks columns, and is set to have no leading column and groups of 3

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" =  Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_, type text})),
leading=0, groupsof=3,
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each List.Split( List.RemoveFirstN(Record.ToList( _),leading), groupsof) ),
#"Added Custom0" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom0", each Text.Combine(List.FirstN(Record.ToList(_),leading),"|")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom0",{"Custom0", "Custom"}),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn( #"Removed Other Columns", "Custom"),
#"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), "|"), type text}),
#"Merged Columns" = if leading=0 then Table.RemoveColumns(#"Extracted Values",{"Custom0"}) else Table.CombineColumns(#"Extracted Values",{"Custom0", "Custom"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.None),"Custom"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Merged Columns", "Custom", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), List.FirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),leading+groupsof))
in #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'm not completely sure how it works (I'll de-engineer it later), but it did.   I was going down a completely different path with the List.Alternate approach.  Goes to prove I've got a LOT to learn yet about Power Query.  Thanks again.